# ¿Cómo realizar una consulta con PIVOT?

Tags: jquery, sql-server, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2, sql

Hola Amig@s Alguien sabe como hacer esta consulta..
Me ha  pedido para mostrar el numero de autos y aviones
que tienen mis clientes, Realizando una consulta con [pivot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017)....
[image: Esta es mi tabla PEDIDO]

Lo deseo que me salga es esto...

[image: Así debe mostrarme]

Estaba intentando así pero bota error de pivot...

```
pivot(PEDIDO),
SUM(cantidad), 
for producto
in(Autos,avion)) as Pivot
Order by 2  DESC;
```

Gracias de Antemano....

Answer (score 3):

Si tu consulta solo manejará dos columnas, no necesitas hacer un `PIVOT` lo resuelves de manera más sencilla con un agrupamiento común y una suma condicional, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT Cliente,
       SUM(CASE WHEN producto = 'Autos' THEN cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS 'Autos',
       SUM(CASE WHEN producto = 'avion' THEN cantidad ELSE 0 END) AS 'avion'
       FROM Pedido
       GROUP BY Cliente
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberías crear 3 tablas para administrar de forma más eficiente los datos:
Tabla a: idcliente, idproducto, cantidad
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla b: idproducto, Producto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla c: Idcliente, nombre
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y luego, con la siguiente sentencia obtendrás el resultado deseado:

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @columns = N'';
SELECT @columns+= N', P.' + QUOTENAME(Producto)
FROM (
SELECT Producto
FROM b
GROUP BY idProducto,Producto ORDER BY idProducto OFFSET 0 rows) AS x;
SET @sql = N'
SELECT cliente, ' + STUFF(@columns,1,2,'') + '
FROM (SELECT a.idcliente,cliente,sum(cantidad) as cantidad,Producto  
FROM a 
inner join b ON (a.idproducto=b.idproducto)
inner join c ON (a.idcliente=c.idcliente)
group by a.idcliente,cliente,Producto) AS J PIVOT (SUM(Cantidad) 
FOR Producto IN (' + STUFF(REPLACE(@Columns,', p.[', ',['),1,1,'') + ')) AS p;';
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta manera, podrás agregar nuevos nombre, nuevos artículos o productos sin tener que modificar ni la estructura de la tabla, ni la sintaxis de la consulta SQL.

Para mejor rendimiento (en caso que tus datos crezcan), debe agregarles índices a las tablas y si quieres, la integridad la manejas con las relaciones.

Saludos